# Webscraping using Python BeautifulSoup Contents.Text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Python 3.6.2, Requests and BeautifulSoup4. But it won't allow me to use a certain property/attribute. Here is the code.

Following this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk 21:11

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://targetwebsite.com"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

 g_data=soup.find_all("h3",{"itemprop":"name"})
 #print(g_data)

for x in g_data:
    print(x.contents[1].text)<---offending line.
```

Says that there is no such 
attribute/property and can't choose when I hit Tab after contents[1].

I have tried this in the Python Idle as well as in the command prompt.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably are hitting a navigatable string object, not a tag object. Be sure to [read the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) on the `.contents` attribute. You may want to be using the `.children` generator instead or, merely use the navagatable string as a string. (It won't have a `.text` because it's already a string!)

Comment: could you post sample html

Comment: Without knowing the actual URL, it would be difficult to help.